# Numpy install error

Tags: numpy

tengo Python 3.8 x64 y me gustaría instalar numpy, ya que al tratar de importar numpy, aparece el siguiente error:

```
"D:\Python Dani jiji\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "D:/Python Dani jiji/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python Dani jiji/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

La cuestión, es que cuando utilizo los comandos `pip install numpy` o `pip3 install numpy`, aparece el siguiente error:

```
Command ""D:\Python Dani jiji\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "D:\Python Dani jiji\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip" inst
all --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\cavs9\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z21comws\overlay --no-warn-script-locat
ion --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel Cython>=0.29.14" failed with error cod
e 1 in None
```

Alguna recomendación? No me manejo mucho con este mundo.

Gracias!!

Comment: Y si intentas `python -m pip install numpy` ?

Comment: Exactamente el mismo error :(

Answer (score 0):

Posibles soluciones:

## 1 Que haya dos módulos llamados Numpy

Ve hacia el directorio donde están tus librerías y busca si tienes dos llamadas `Numpy` en ese caso elimina ambas y vuelve a instalar Numpy con pip

## 2 Python 3.8 Error con numpy

No conozco que haya ningún error con `Numpy` y la versión 3.8 de python. Pero prueba a instalar Python 3.7 con `Numpy` a ver si te da el mismo error

## 3 Solución clasica

Desinstala python y todos los paquetes y vuelvelos a instalar, tal vez haya habido un archivo o fichero corrupto.